# How to make trigger command using watchman?

Tags: watchman

Hi I will be using watchman to upload images. The images will have folders so I will be using `.json` to make the command.

These are my images:

```
/home/user/Documents/Images/folder1/image1.png
/home/user/Documents/Images/folder2/image2.png
```

I have a list of export environment variables `watchman_env`

```
export CONDA_ENV=image_uploader
export IMG_FOLDER=/home/user/Documents/Images
export UPLOADER_SCRIPT=/home/user/Documents/Script/uploader.sh
export PYTHON_UPLOADER=/home/user/Documents/Script/img_uploader.py
export JSON_TRIGGER=/home/user/Documents/Script/uploader.json
```

This is my uploader script, `~/Script/uploader.sh`

```
. watchman_env
conda run -n $CONDA_ENV python $PYTHON_UPLOADER $IMG_FOLDER
```

This is my json configuration, `~/Script/uploader.json`:

```
["trigger", "/home/user/Documents/Images", {
  "name": "img_uploader",
  "expression": ["match", "**/*.png"],
  "command": ["/home/user/Documents/Script/uploader.sh"]
}]
```

I run the command using another bash file, `init.sh`, since I want to run some few more commands.

```
. watchman_env
watchman --json-command < $JSON_TRIGGER
```

When I run `uploader.sh` my python script uploads the two images. However, when I run `init.sh`, it does not trigger. What is wrong with my code? And is that correctly how to use json trigger?

wathman version: 4.9.0

Answer (score 1):

I just added to the expression `wholename` and finally worked.

```
["trigger", "/home/user/Documents/Images", {
  "name": "img_uploader",
  "expression": ["match", "**/*.png", "wholename"],
  "command": ["/home/user/Documents/Script/uploader.sh"]
}]
```